# Unable to publish shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have build a shiny application which works completely fine when I am running it through RStudio. But when I am trying to publish my R application through Shiny it is getting as error. This is the message below:

```
Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    box

Loading required package: ggplot2

Attaching package: ‘plotly’

The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:

    last_plot

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    layout

Creating a generic function for ‘toJSON’ from package ‘jsonlite’ in package ‘googleVis’

Welcome to googleVis version 0.6.4

Please read Google's Terms of Use
before you start using the package:
https://developers.google.com/terms/

Note, the plot method of googleVis will by default use
the standard browser to display its output.

See the googleVis package vignettes for more details,
or visit https://github.com/mages/googleVis.

To suppress this message use:
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(googleVis))

Warning in file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'Cleaned_Prop_Data.csv': No such file or directory
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : cannot open the connection
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if the file Cleaned_Prop_Data.csv is available on your local machine but not wherever you are publishing your app.